# Integrating $y=x^2 - 1$ over $x = -2$ to $x = 4$ to find the area

Tags: definite-integrals, area

When I started this I went straight for integrating $x^2 -1$ and came up with $\frac{x^3}{3}  - x$.

However the notes I am using say I should have used $y = (x-1)(x+1)$. I have tried both and they provide different answers. I realize that $x^2 -1$ equals $(x-1)(x+1)$.

What I am unsure of is what indicators should I be looking for to tell me that I should factorize the function before integrating it ?

Also when dealing with a rule that says if $y\leq 0$ then do blah blah , or if $y \geq 0$ then do bah bah. How do you know which to do if $y = 0$ as it falls in to both rules.

thanks

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you work with $x^2 - 1$ or $(x+1)(x-1)$ because, as you have noted, they are equal. Can you show how you got different answers?

Comment: You're right that you should get $\int_{-2}^4 (x^2-1)dx = \left[ \dfrac {x^3}{3}-x\right]_{-2}^4$.

Comment: I am unsure of the scripting/coding used to make fractions tidy etc so bare with me…When i used (x-1)(x+1) I came up with 3 different ranges I needed to use for integration [-2,-1], [-1,1] and [1,4]. My original answer using the formula above as shown by Bye_Wolrd got me 54/3. The correct answer I am told is 62/3 which comes from 54/3 + 4/3 + 4/3 (I got this when I broke the values into the above mentioned 3 ranges)

Comment: Why would you want to integrate it as $(x-1)(x+1)$? That looks like an integration by parts problem, much more difficult than doing it the straightforward way.

Comment: OP, one of those $\frac{4}{3}$ should be a $-\frac{4}{3}$. You did something wrong. Maybe you were finding the area between the curve and the $x$-axis, and that's why you changed the sign to a positive? [Or perhaps the problem was supposed to be about area...]

Comment: I used (x^3/3 - x) for each interval and then added them all together, but for [-1,1] I multiplied it by -1 as it was a negative area at first.

Comment: thanks anon. I have updated the title as my goal was to find the area

Comment: If your goal is to find the area then you can't just integrate the function willy-nilly, which justifies splitting the domain up into parts where the function is positive/negative so you can change the sign of the negative area.

Comment: ohh thanks, this part I did not know